# How to remove decimals from Price in magento 2.3.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i want to remove decimals from Price in magento 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Use the Plugin concept and try to implement the logic for `Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface`